# pandas value_count function bin order change

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, intervals, bins

I am using value_count and bin to get one view our my database.

```
bin = np.concatenate((np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(10,100,10),np.arange(100,1000,100)))
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  20,  30,
    40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700,
   800, 900])
```

My sample data is following:

```
summary_data['STOP_mean']
536826    4.100000
536827    1.500000
536828    2.000000
Name: STOP_mean, Length: 536829, dtype: float64
```

However, bin provide result as following:

***which is not same order*** as pandas result.

```
summary_data['STOP_mean'].value_counts(bins = bin)


(-0.001, 1.0]     172259
(1.0, 2.0]        163468
(2.0, 3.0]         57479
(10.0, 20.0]       30479
(3.0, 4.0]         29108
(4.0, 5.0]         18480
```

why `(10.0,20.0]` pop right after `(2.0.3.0]`

Already tried `reset_index` and `sort_index` does not work. (Looks like it is interval index. How to reset that one?)

`sort_index`
result:

```
<bound method Series.sort_index of (-0.001, 1.0]     172259
(1.0, 2.0]        163468
(2.0, 3.0]         57479
(10.0, 20.0]       30479
(3.0, 4.0]         29108
(4.0, 5.0]         18480
```

---

## Solved

`sort_index(axis=0)` solved problem

Comment: use `.sort_index()`

Comment: sort_index() does not work. see above. Do I need to make it categorical data?

Comment: Thank you @ALollz. This is interesting. Sort_index(axis=0) works, sort_index()does not, even through axis=0 is default...

Comment: Are you sure you added () after sort Index in the first case? It looks like you haven’t actually called the method in your output